# I have a error when I building new items in monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a error when I add a New file(spritefonts, .fbx, etc.).

[image: image1]

Error's says:

> "Gravity   Cod Description Project File Riga Stato eliminazione
>   Errore exit command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools\MGCB.exe" /@:"C:\Users\corpo\Documents\Programming\Monogame\Ice vs Ice\Ice vs Ice\Content\Content.mgcb" /platform:DesktopGL /outputDir:"C:\Users\corpo\Documents\Programming\Monogame\Ice vs Ice\Ice vs Ice\Content\bin\DesktopGL"Ice/Content/Fonts/File.spritefont"`

[image: image2]

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong during the content pipeline project compilation step.  Specifically, it is trying to load `FreeType6.dll`, but it isn't present.

Comment: See some [discussion about this issue](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/5736) on monogame's support forum.  It looks like installing the Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable package should solve it.  You can get it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Comment: @BradleyUffner but Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable package also works for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Yes, the name is deceptive. It isn't related directly to vs2017. It is just a support library for things *written* in vs2012. Something in monogame must require it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Works! thank you for the help. :)